# Maven 3 transitive dependencies of test dependency are marked as compile, why?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jira, dependency-management

I observed a strange behaviour in my maven 3.0.5 / JDK 1.7 build. Within the dependency tree I found **TEST**-resources that have transitive **COMPILE** dependencies (see section 1 below).

This triggers than in a subsequent build phase that **maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20** unpacks these resources to the target/class folder (In effect this is the expected/normal behaviour, but not desired here, see section 2 below)

On an other machine, (same Maven/JDK version) these dependencies are *not* marked as **COMPILE** and the build is running fine.

**Any hints why the transitive dependencies are marked as compile?**

*[UPDATE 1]* I am little bit confused about the -X output... the *jira maven plugins* seems to do some extra magic... Does "Included..." means that the jira plugin uses the specified version of the dependency-plugin?

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20
[DEBUG]   Included: com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:jar:4.2.20
[..]
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.0
```

**(1) Dependency Tree**

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree (default-cli) @  ---
[INFO] com.example.jira.plugins:example-plugin-solman-connector:atlassian-plugin:6.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.activeobjects:activeobjects-plugin:jar:0.23.2:provided
       [..]
[INFO] +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.8:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.8:provided
       [..]
[INFO] +- com.atlassian.jira:jira-core:jar:6.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.jira:jira-api:jar:6.2.2:provided
       [..]            
[INFO] |  +- com.atlassian.cargo-test-runner:cargo-test-runner:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-uberjar:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- saxpath:saxpath:jar:1.0-FCS:**compile** <-------
[INFO] |  |  |  +- msv:msv:jar:20020414:**compile**
[INFO] |  |  |  +- relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:**compile**
[INFO] |  |  |  +- isorelax:isorelax:jar:20020414:**compile**
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- ant:ant:jar:1.5.4:test
```

**(2) Build Log including effective pom**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building example-plugin-solman-connector 6.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] ******************* BUILD VARIABLES ****************************************** 
     [..]
     [echo] ******************************************************************************
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:copy-bundled-dependencies (default-copy-bundled-dependencies) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2-atlassian-1/gson-2.2.2-atlassian-1.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/saxpath/saxpath/1.0-FCS/saxpath-1.0-FCS.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3.4-RC8/xpp3-1.1.3.4-RC8.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/dom4j/dom4j/1.4/dom4j-1.4.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6.1/commons-beanutils-1.6.1.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] Unpacking /home/atlassian/.m2-atlassian-build-maven3-nexus-deploy/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes with includes "" and excludes "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,META-INF/*.DSA,META-INF/*.SF"
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:compress-resources (default-compress-resources) @ example- INFO]  [..]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ example-plugin-solman-connector -- [..]-
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:filter-plugin-descriptor (default-filter-plugin-descriptor) @ example-plugin-solman-connector --- [..]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] Compiling 30 source files to /home/atlassian/x/build/target/classes [..]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-manifest (default-generate-manifest) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] No manifest instructions found, adding only non-OSGi manifest attributes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-rest-docs (default-generate-rest-docs) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:copy-test-bundled-dependencies (default-copy-test-bundled-dependencies) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/atlassian/x/build/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:filter-test-plugin-descriptor (default-filter-test-plugin-descriptor) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-test-manifest (default-generate-test-manifest) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:unit-test (default-unit-test) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[..]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:validate-manifest (default-validate-manifest) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---[..]
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:jar (default-jar) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/atlassian/x/build/target/example-plugin-solman-connector-6.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jira_6.2.2-build_unknown_unknown.jar [..]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:generate-obr-artifact (default-generate-obr-artifact) @ example-plugin-solman-connector --- [..]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:validate-test-manifest (default-validate-test-manifest) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:4.2.20:test-jar (default-test-jar) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building example-plugin-solman-connector 6.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom (default-cli) @ example-plugin-solman-connector ---
[INFO] 
Effective POMs, after inheritance, interpolation, and profiles are applied:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>[..]        
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>[..]</parent>
  <groupId>com.example.jira.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-plugin-solman-connector</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>
  <developers>
  <scm>[..]</scm>
  <distributionManagement>[..]</distributionManagement>
  <properties>[..]</properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
      <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.23.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      [..]
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      [..]
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
      <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.11</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-tests</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-func-tests</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    [..]
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    [..]
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>[..]</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>[..]</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>[..]</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>[..]</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>[..]</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>/home/atlassian/x/build/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>atlassian-plugin.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>/home/atlassian/x/build/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>atlassian-plugin.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/atlassian/x/build/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/home/atlassian/x/build/target</directory>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-beta-7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1-alpha-2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.20</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-amps-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.2.20</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
          <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.20</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-mvn-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>mvn-install</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-copy-test-bundled-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-test-bundled-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compress-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compress-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-filter-plugin-descriptor</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>filter-plugin-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unit-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-filter-test-plugin-descriptor</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>filter-test-plugin-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-generate-test-manifest</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-test-manifest</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-generate-manifest</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-manifest</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-generate-rest-docs</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-rest-docs</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-validate-manifest</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate-manifest</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-generate-obr-artifact</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate-obr-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-validate-test-manifest</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate-test-manifest</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-copy-bundled-dependencies</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-bundled-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-mvn-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>mvn-deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
              <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
              <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <productVersion>6.2.2</productVersion>
          <productDataVersion>5.2</productDataVersion>
          <allowGoogleTracking>false</allowGoogleTracking>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>[..]
        </executions>
        <configuration>[..]
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>[..]</executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        [..]
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
   [..]
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: First you have not fixed the maven plugin versions cause the effective pom shows several old plugin versions. Furthermore if you have a different machine you will get different maven plugin versions if you would compare the output of this build. Apart from that you should use maven-dependency:2.8 instead of earlier version...

Comment: You are right... I should have also added my master pom to clarify the stuff. Within my master pom, there is a _pluginManagement_ section which seals the actual plugin to use. The maven-dependency-plugin version here is 2.5.1. Due to historical reasons I'am using some old plugins. I tried to upgrade the dependency plugin to 2.8, but there is no effect. I have still the same problem.