# Maven brings "test" transitive dependency as "compile"

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

When I run "mvn dependency:tree" for my project it shows the following:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxxx ---
[INFO] com.xxx.xxx:xxxxx:war:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
...
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.34.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20080701:test
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.34.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.34.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO] |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.12:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.3:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.12:test
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0:test
>>>[INFO] |     |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.18:test
[INFO] |     +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.9:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:test
[INFO] +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.34.0:test
...
```

As you see on the marked line, the xml-apis has "compile" scope, and as result it is packed into .war file. Why could it happen?

More interestingly it happens only while Java5 is used, for Java6 the dependency appears as "test".

Maven version: 3.0.4

Comment: Doesn't `xml-api` appear elsewhere as another dependance ?

Comment: test dependencies will never be packaged into a war except you have done something weird. Please show your pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise I know, but for some reason I have it! The pom file is quite large, there are several parent poms... I have not tried to extract minimal code sample, quite tedious, but absolutely nothing special about `selenium-htmlunit-driver` dependency, declared as usual.

Comment: Very interesting: if I do `mvn dependency:tree` it shows the dep as `compile`, but if I do `mvn -Dverbose dependency:tree` the dep becomes `test`. I am now pretty sure it is a bug somewhere in the maven. As a workaround I declared the `xml-apis` dependency in my pom explicitly, seems it works now.

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is not declared in any of my poms. When I've added the dep in exclusion list of the `selenium-htmlunit-driver`, it disappeared. As I understand it means that it is not dep of anything else.

Comment: Similar question, but now answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

In my case an entry in the dependencyManagement of a parent pom set the scope of the dependent artefact to compile. Actually I omitted the scope tag which effectively is the same as setting it to compile. Changing it to provided helped.
Seems the scope in dependencyManagement takes precedence over the transitive scope. Which makes sense but can still cause confusion when all you wanted to do is define the version.

It was actually not hard to spot: Looking at the effective-pom showed the dependencyManagement entry.

Comment: Ran into the exact same scenario, thanks for the explanation!!

Answer (score 7):

Study the output of the following Maven command.

```
mvn -X dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

That should tell you why Maven upgraded the scope from test to compile.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at [xercesImpl](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=xerces/xercesImpl/2.10.0/xercesImpl-2.10.0.pom) it contains a dependency to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile with the scope compile so the display of dependency plugin is correct. The usage of `-Dverbose` will do things as written in the docs:

> Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency tree.

Apart from the above a test dependency as in your case is never being packaged into a war file.

**There must be an other source of the same dependency which causes the packaging into the war**

Furthermore the change in behaviour in relationship with adding explicit xml-apis to your pom is a supplemental evidence for this.

Comment: I don't think you read my question with full attention. If you take a look at any other test dependency, e.g. htmlunit, it has all its dependencies as compile, but only xml-apis is displayed as `compile`. The `-Dverbose` should just include omitted nodes (yes, it happens), but in my case it is also changing scope. And the `.jar` is packaged into war. Any ideas how to find the 'other source'? My knowledge of Maven tells me that there are no other sources.

Comment: You have to start at your war artifact and see via mvn dependency:tree where all the artifacts are comming from.

Comment: The fragment of the tree output is in my question. The only source I see is the `selenium-htmlunit-driver`. And if I `<exclude>` the `xml-apis` from the driver, the dep disappears from the tree.

Comment: Your output starts not at the war which i mentioned to be the start point of such an analysis.

Comment: The `...` means I've omitted a lot of other output which is quite large and irrelevant to the question. I've added back a few lines for you.